# Right way to start with a Bootstrap subtheme?

Tags: theming

I create my first [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) subtheme (version 7.x-3.0) and I have 3 questions:

**1)** Theres is the file css/style.css which has more than 6400 lines, is this normal. I expected to it to be an empty page to start adding my custom css styles. Is this right?

**2)** I guess that I should not add anything in css/style.css and create my own files.E.g: blocks.css, prodcuct.css. Am I right?

**3)** How to create and declare a new **.less** file. E.g: blocks.less, products.less, etc. I know that the .css files must be declared in the .info file, but not sure about this kind of files.

I uploaded a capture where you can see the folder structure of the subtheme.

[image]

Comment: Import your own less files into the style.less file. The whole lot (your files and the libraries) are compiled into the style.css file. You are free to structure your imported files any way you want, but check out [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) for guidance. If you don't like less you can use the sass port. You can also customise the Bootstrap source code to include only what you want and need and not the whole lot, but do that only if your requirements demand it.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, there is a guide to begin with subtheming with Bootstrap [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010). And I recommand you to download the **starter kit** to get ready-to-use subtheme.

**1) and 2)** 
To create a subtheme, you don't have to edit any files in your base theme. Just create a custom theme, in `sites/all/themes/`, just next your `bootstrap` folder, and declare the `yourtheme.info` file like this:

```
name = yourtheme
description = Custom Bootstrap subtheme
core = 7.x
base theme = bootstrap
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

It is going to make the **heritance** of all your bootstrap files automatically.

You can create a **new empty css** file, in `yourtheme/css/style.css`, and customize.

You can also create multiple css files, as you said, but you have to declare it in the `.info` file aswell.

3) LESS is supported by Bootstrap. You just have to follow the guide I told you and have a local LESS compiler to generate CSS.

**======**

**BIG EDIT:**

**======**

**How to set up a new Bootstrap subtheme**

**A)** Download [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) project (7.3 is fine to me). Place the bootstrap folder in `sites/all/themes/`.

**B)** Download [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) project, which is required by Bootstrap. Go to `yoursite/admin/config/development/jquery_update` and set the default jQuery version to **1.9**.

**C)** In your `bootstrap` folder, you're gonna find `bootstrap_subtheme` folder. Move it to `sites/all/themes/` and **name** it `banana` (let's suppose your custom theme is called Banana). So you have `bootstrap` and `banana` folders at the **same level**.

**D)** In `banana`, **rename** the `bootstrap_subtheme.info.starterkit` file to `banana.info`. And edit its content like this:

```
name = Banana, a Bootstrap Sub-theme
description = A Bootstrap Sub-theme called Banana.
core = 7.x
base theme = bootstrap
```

**E)** Now you have a pretty new Banana theme, inheriting all from Bootstrap theme, and that you can **activate** in `yoursite/admin/appearance/`.

**F)** If you want to try a customization, go to `sites/all/themes/banana/css` and make a little change to `style.css` (see, it is not 6400+ lines ;-)). Refresh your site and see if it is applied.

**G)** If you want to work with **LESS**, you have to set up a [local LESS compiler](http://lesscss.org/#using-less) on your computer. This one seems to be simple to install and configure. *Personaly, I use SASS and Ruby Gem to compile, so I cannot give your further information about another compiler here. Maybe someone will.*

**H)** Once you're ready with your compiler, you just need to make your **edit** in `sites/all/themes/banana/less/` folder. All the `.less` files that appear here are included in `style.less`. This is the one you have to compile (only this one) to generate `css/style.css`. Bootstrap gives you **3 empty files** where you can put your code, `content.less`, `footer.less`, `header.less`. You can use them or just **create new ones** (don't forget to import them in `style.less` if you add new files).

**I)** Make some **changes**, **compile** and **refresh** your site. See if it is applied.

I wish you good luck (and a merry Christmas ^^)

Comment: Small addition - I don't know specifically about 6400+ lines, but Bootstrap is notoriously a very heavy, erm, would you call it a 'library'? Not sure, but either way it doesn't surprise me to hear that there are thousands of lines of CSS. It's not exactly built to be lightweight

Comment: Is it not called a "frontend framework"? And yes it is quite heavy.

Comment: @Djouuuuh Thanks, but I had no problem at all to create the subtheme. The structure you see in the capture it is the subtheme, not the base theme.

Comment: @Clive you are right, but the interesting thing about Bootstrap library is that it provide a Framework with many Components which are really useful for fast develpment.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I'm not knocking it - Bootstrap has its place, definitely. I was just pointing out that the free functionality comes at the price of a pretty bulky front-end framework (thanks @Djouuuuh :P)

Comment: Sorry @chefnelone but why have you an existing css file with 6400+ lines in your fresh sub theme? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Djouuuuh I can't say. I just followed this tutorial: https://www.gaslampmedia.com/tutorial-drupal-bootstrap-subtheme-less/

Comment: If I were you, I'd follow the official guide rather than this tuto :/

Comment: I tried but I found it hard to follow since it seems to me a litle unclear. So you think that these 6000 lines are not right, do you?

Comment: Oh I see. Let me make it clearer in my edit.

Comment: Here @chefnelone, let me know!

Comment: I'll try it asap, I really appreciate this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19714/discussion-between-chefnelone-and-djouuuuh).

Comment: @Djouuuuh I started a chat.

Comment: Sorry I'm not in my office anymore. I'm preparing Christmas eve :/

Comment: No worries, merry Christmas ^^ !!

Comment: I came across this post too late, but I would like to comment on it. I installed bootstrap theme, but there was no `bootstrap_subtheme` directory to move, so I did everything minus that.