# No sub theme folder inside bootstrap theme folder

Tags: theming

I just installed [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) 3 theme in Drupal 7, but the subtheme folder is missing. I am new to Drupal and am following online tutorials but no result. All instructions direct me to a sub theme folder in themes>bootstrap> bootstrap-subtheme, but there is no such folder. I removed the theme and reinstalled but still no folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the `starterkits` folder then choose between `less` or `cdn`.

For more information, have a look on files within `docs` folder

Answer (score 0):

Just create the sub-theme folder manually. The folder name you'd use for it will be the machine name of your subtheme.

For more details, refer to:

- "[Creating a sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125)" (= Community documentation that applies to any sub-theme).
- "[Sub-theming](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!subtheme!README.md/group/subtheme/7)" (= documentation about sub-theming specific to Drupal's [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme).

If you prefer to look at a great (I think) example of a (contributed) Bootstrap sub-theme, then have a look at the [Bootstrap Business](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_business) theme.

Note: the question about "[Right way to start with a Bootstrap subtheme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141538)" contains a lot of details to get started with such sub-theme ...

Answer (score 0):

See http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!subtheme!README.md/group/subtheme/7.

> To start with, you need to choose an Existing Starterkit.
>
> - [CDN Starterkit](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/starterkits%21cdn%21README.md/group/subtheme_cdn/7) - uses the "out-of-the-box" CSS and JavaScript files served by the jsDelivr CDN.
> - [LESS Starterkit](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/starterkits%21less%21README.md/group/subtheme_less/7) - uses the Bootstrap Framework source files and a local LESS preprocessor. Create a New Sub-theme
>
> Then follow these steps:
>
> - Copy over one of the starterkits you have chosen from the `./bootstrap/starterkits` folder into `sites/all/themes` or a
>     respective `sites/*/themes` folder.
> - Rename the folder to a unique machine readable name. This will be your sub-theme's "name". For this example and future examples we'll
>     use subtheme.
> - Rename `./subtheme/cdn.starterkit` or, if using the LESS Starterkit, `./subtheme/less.starterkit` to match the folder name and
>     append .`info` (e.g. ./subtheme/subtheme.info).
> - Open `./subtheme/subtheme.info` and change the name, description and any other properties to suite your needs.
>
> > WARNING: Ensure that the .starterkit suffix is not present on your
> >     sub-theme's .info filename. This suffix is simply a stop gap measure
> >     to ensure that the bundled starter kit sub-theme cannot be enabled or
> >     used directly. This helps people unfamiliar with Drupal avoid
> >     modifying the starter kit sub-theme directly and instead forces them
> >     to create a new sub-theme to modify.